# Principal Component Analysis as a step between STFT and MFCC

Tags: fourier-transform, spectrogram, mfcc, stft, music

For computing Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients you can use already calculated STFTs as a basis and perform the Mel frequency mapping on it.

**My question:** Does it make a significant difference if I calculate the STFTs, perform a PCA-transform on them and then calculate the MFCC compared to computing the PCA-transform at the very end on the MFCCs?

In both cases we have two dimensionality reductions (PCA and MFCC) and I'm not sure weather the order makes a difference.

Answer (score -2):

One dimensionality reduction method (PCA) is linear, the other ([MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum)) is  not. It  is thus unlikely that there is no difference at all since they probably do not commute. One serves more decorrelation, the other feature extraction.

The importance of the order thus depends a lot on your signal class, and what your purpose is.

Comment: Thank you. You're totally right regarding the linearity/ log-scale. I'm just wondering since in literature about music classification PCA is always (if) applied after the MFCCs have been computed. But to allow comparison between lets say a Feature Learning and MFCC-approach (both depending on STFT beforehand) it makes much more sense to me to apply PCA directly on the magnitude spectrum of the STFT....what do you think?

Comment: If you are taking the magnitude of the STFT, this is another non-linear transform. Quite often in signal processing, features (non linear) are extracted first, followed by linear (decorrelation) then non-linear again: think about quantization/transform/compression. I would not use PCA on absolute STFT: others transforms for positive signals like NMF (non-negative matrix factorization) could be more practically useful.

Comment: I must admit that I find it hard to understand why NNMF should be better in this case than PCA when talking solely about dimensionality reduction. If I would use it to obtain features, NNMF would be beneficial - but e.g. reducing the dataset to 99% variance, is there really a benefit? Orthogonality and negative coefficients aren't a problem here I think...thanks for your reply!

Comment: The way you want to apply PCA on spectrograms is not clear to me yet. A spectrogram yields a rectangular matrix. Then, in many cases, PCA sounds more natural to me on symmetrically-distributed data. Which spectrograms are not. Cusps due to time-frequency zero-crossing somehow render SFTF not stationnary. Back to the actual question: what do you really want to do?

Comment: Actual question: Does the order make a difference: STFT -> MFCC -> PCA or STFT -> PCA -> MFCC. And if yes, what difference? Since the PCA applied on STFTs is applied on much more data I expect the outcome more relevant than on already compressed MFCCs. 

(It's clear that the STFT-matrix will be flattened first and multiple STFTs will be stacked together to form the matrix for PCA. Surely data will be normalized.)